# Is there a way to replace specific value in a list with the adjacent values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, data-cleaning

My code is supposed to change the missing value to its valid immediate adjacent values. However, it does not seem to be running correctly and I'm not quite sure where the mistake lies.

So the missing value has to be corrected to the average of its adjacent values. However, if there are consecutive missing values, then they should be corrected with the valid adjacent value. Only basic python functions like for loops and if/else are to be used.

```
    data = [1, -999, -999, 3, 4]
    missing = -999
    for i, num in enumerate(data):
        if num == missing:
            if [i-1] and [i+1] != missing:
                data[i] = (data[i-1] + data[i+1]) / 2
            elif [i-1] != missing and [i+1] == missing:
                data[i] = data[i-1]
            elif [i+1] != missing and [i-1] == missing:
                data[i] = data[i+1]
            else:
                data[i] = data[i]
            print(data)
```

For example:

```
    data = [1, 2, -999, 4, 5], [1, -999, -999, 3, 4], [-999, -999, 3, 4, 5], [-999, -999, -999, -999, -999]
    expected output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 1, 3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 3, 4, 5], [-999, -999, -999, -999, -999]
```

Comment: `[i-1]` by itself has nothing to do with the list `data`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data[i-1]` and `data[i+1]` inside if `num == missing :`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, -999, -999]
missing = -999
for i, num in enumerate(data):
    if (num == missing) and (i not in [0, len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1]):
        if (data[i-1] != missing) and (data[i+1] != missing):
            data[i] = (data[i-1] + data[i+1]) / 2
        elif (data[i-1] != missing) and (data[i+1] == missing):
            data[i] = data[i-1]
            data[i+1] = data[i+2]
        elif (data[i+1] != missing) and (data[i-1] == missing):
            data[i] = data[i+1]
            data[i-1] = data[i-2]
    elif (num == missing) and (i == 0):
        if data[i+1] != missing:
            data[i] = data[i+1]
        else:
            data[i] = data[i+2]
    elif (num == missing) and (i in [len(data) - 2, len(data) - 1]):
        if data[i-1] != missing:
            data[i] = data[i-1]
        else:
            data[i] = data[i-2]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[3, 3.0, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: oh it worked! but what if my data is [1, 2, 3, -999, -999] ? this did not worked on that data. Do i have to add another elif at the bottom?

Comment: This answer hard-codes the range of the search for valid adjacent values to just 2. It will break when a valid adjacent value is more than 2 indices away, e.g. `[-999, -999, -999, 3, 4]`.

Comment: @blhsing I know, in the OPs examples the most -999 he had was 2

Comment: @blhsing I was testing on the lists he had

Comment: @U12-Forward The description says "if there are consecutive missing values, then they should be corrected with the valid adjacent value." It does not mention a limit of just 2 to the range of the search for a valid adjacent value. You should therefore not aim to just satisfy the test cases but to satisfy the spirit of the description.